# Overriding the Pokemon name

Tags: c#

I have Pokemon.cs here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PokemonPocket{
    public class PokemonMaster{
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public int NoToEvolve {get; set;}
        public  string EvolveTo {get; set;}

        public PokemonMaster(string name, int noToEvolve, string evolveTo){
            this.Name = name;
            this.NoToEvolve = noToEvolve;
            this.EvolveTo = evolveTo;
        }
    }
}
```

and I have created this program here called Program.cs:

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    
    namespace PokemonPocket
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //PokemonMaster list for checking pokemon evolution availability.    
                List<PokemonMaster> pokemonMasters = new List<PokemonMaster>(){
                new PokemonMaster("Pikachu", 2, "Raichu"),
                new PokemonMaster("Eevee", 3, "Flareon"),
                new PokemonMaster("Charmander", 1, "Charmeleon")
                };
                // Use "Environment.Exit(0);" if you want to implement an exit of the console program
                PokemonMenu(pokemonMasters);
            }
            static void PokemonMenu(List<PokemonMaster> pokemans)
            {
                // From now on myDictionary is available for any menu option 
                var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    
                while (true)
                { // <- loop until exit option (key 'Q') is pressed
                    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Pokemon Pocket App!");
                    Console.WriteLine("(1). Add Pokemon to my pocket");
                    Console.WriteLine("(2). List Pokemon(s) in my pocket");
                    Console.WriteLine("(3). Check if I can evolve Pokemon");
                    Console.WriteLine("(4). Evolve Pokemon\n");
                    Console.Write("Please only enter [1,2,3,4] or Q to exit:");
    
                    char menu = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
    
                    if (menu == '1')
                    { //Part 1
                        Console.Write("Enter Pokemon Name :");
                        string name = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Enter Pokemon HP : ");
                        int hp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    
                        Console.Write("Enter Pokemon EXP : ");
                        int exp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        if (myDictionary.Count <= 0)
                        {
                            myDictionary.Add("Pokemon's Name", name);
                            myDictionary.Add("Pokemon's HP", hp.ToString());
                            myDictionary.Add("Pokemon's EXP", exp.ToString());
                            Console.WriteLine("Pokemon has been added!");
    
                        }
                    }
                    else if (menu == '2')
                    { //Part 2
                        foreach (var v in myDictionary)
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{1}: {0}", v.Value, v.Key));
                    }
    
                    else if (menu == '3') //Part  3
                    {
                        if (!myDictionary.TryGetValue("Pokemon's Name", out var myPokemon))
                        {
                            // No pokemon in pocket so just exit
    
                            Console.WriteLine("You have no pokemon!");
                            continue;
                        }
    
                        var matchedPokemon = pokemans.Find(p => p.Name == myPokemon);
    
                        if (matchedPokemon != default)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Can evolve a pokeman!");
                            Console.WriteLine($"{matchedPokemon.Name} --> {matchedPokemon.EvolveTo}");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (menu == 'Q')
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("App exited!");
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After adding the Pokemon in 1, when I input 2 this is what the program displays:

```
Pokemon's Name: Charmander
Pokemon's HP: 20
Pokemon's EXP: 30
```

When I input 4, I want the name to be overrided into Charmeleon, something like evolution in original Pokemon. Then when I input 2, I want it to display this:

```
Pokemon's Name: Charmeleon
Pokemon's HP: 0 //hp will become 0 when evolved
Pokemon's EXP: 0 //hp will become 0 when evolved
Pokemon's Skill = Solar power //skill will now be there as original input doesnt have skill
```

How do i do so?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to update it, but you could do something like

- Read in the pokemon's Value (`TryGetValue`)
- Remove the existing Key (`Remove`)
- Add the value back in with the new key (the new name) (`Add`)

Because Key of a `Dictionary` cannot be updated